# Where is the missing energy from the Big Bang?

Tags: big-bang

"They" say the Big Bang created 1 billion particles of anti-matter for every 1 billion and 1 particles of normal matter.  That the 1 billion particles of anti-matter were annihilated when they met 1 billion matter particles, thus leaving 1 matter particle.  But people forget that leaves the energy-equivalent of 2 billion particles for every particle of matter.  Currently "they" think the universe is 4% normal matter and 96% something else.  But when the universe started at the Big Bang it was 0.00000005% normal matter ( 1/2,000,000,000 times 100 to get percent) and the remainder is an energy-equivalent.  So where did all the energy go?  Even if this energy-equivalent is what makes up dark energy and dark matter then why isn't there more of it instead of the 96% that we see?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_energy ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect ? Also _"It must be remembered that besides the energy density of the matter there must also be given an energy density of the gravitational field, so that there can be no talk of principles of conservation of energy and momentum for matter alone"_ [E.Einstein, The meaning of Relativity] So by conservation rules we can say that the rest of energy is in between matter, in the fields between matter (gravitational, electromagnetic, etc), in the fields from all the "particles"(matter.energy) in the universe.

Comment: One would say that only local fields have enough energy to affect local matter.But the mass of the rest of the universe is so much bigger then our local matter.We live on earth but earth is part of the solar system,but the solar system gravitates in our galaxy,but our galaxy gravitates in the local cluster of galaxies,and so on.The known universe has a mass of ~$10^{53}$kg, while our local matter is only but a fraction of it.It's a long distance but because it's so much matter the long distance is somehow balanced by the amount of matter.This makes the everywhere fields energy at a local point